# Run sequence of scripts

Tags: scripting

Is there any way to run a sequence of scripts? That is, every x seconds a new script (within a list) starts running, is it possible?

Comment: you can use timers : https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html

Comment: . I tried this way without success:                                             import bpy

def every_2_seconds():
    
    
    
filename = "/full/path/to/myscript.py"
exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'))


    print("Hello World")
    return 2.0


bpy.app.timers.register(every_2_seconds)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: Python has a built-in library for keeping track of time.

Comment: I would like a new script created externally to start running automatically in Blender without having to import it and click on "Run Script"